# ASP.NET MVC route to different address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In the RouteConfig.cs, the default route is

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and this will route `http://www.website13121212.com/home/about` to "Home" controller and "Index" action.

How do I route `http://www.website13121212.com/home/about` to `http://www.website13121212.com/about` and basically using the same "Home" controller and "Index" action?

so that anyone requesting `../home/about` should automatically basically "redirect" to `.../about`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this route at the bottom of all routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "About",
                 url: "/about",
                 defaults: new 
                 {
                      controller = "Home", 
                      action = "About",
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                 });
```

This will route `http://www.website13121212.com/about` to the `About` action in `Home` controller.

Comment: Is this automatically going to redirect the user to `http://www.website13121212.com/about` also so that the user knows that the link/address changed?

Comment: @PKKG Don't remove the default route. Seems you have removed the default route. When you put `{controller}/{action}` , it will be routed using default route.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `{controller}` from the route string. This will say "I don't expect a controller to be provided".